# Getting an optional part in JS Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get ids from urls from Steam, now I am having some problems with some optional parts.

When I started this, all the urls looked like this, and my regex code works fine.

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/261680-%3Aberet%3A
```

The regex will nicely get an id of `753`, and hash of `261680-%3Aberet%3A` and the id part from it `261680`.

Now there are some new urls and my regex completely breaks.

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/Coat%20of%20Arms%20-%20Yellow%20Farmer
```

The regex code I use is:

```
/\/(\d+)\/((\d+)-.*?)($|\?)/
```

Is there a way to have the regex primarily working as the first, getting the two id's and full hash part, but if there is no second id like in the last url, that it just returns the url. Basically, the second id part before the `-` should be optional.

Any other micro-optimizations to the regex would be welcome too, I am not a star at it.

Comment: see if this is what you are looking for [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pQ4oF4/2)

Comment: Thanks it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
/\/(\d+?)\/(([\D\d]+?)\-.*?)($|\?)/i;
```

In your example input contain digit or not digit string. So just try `[\D\d]` for matching the digits and not digits character before the string `-`